# TSQL Searching Rows in another table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Two tables are given

**PilotGroup Table**

```
Pilot            Plane  

Jon Smith      A1-Fighter
Jon Smith   B1-Fighter
Gravell     A2-Fighter
Jon Skeet   A1-Fighter
Jon Skeet   B1-Fighter
Jon Skeet   A4-Fighter
Gravell     A5-Fighter
```

**SouthOperation Table**

```
Plane
A1-Fighter
B1-Fighter
```

The task is to print the pilot names who is trained on both A1-Fighter and B1-Fighter.

I got the result by executing

```
select distinct pilot from PilotGroup  as pg1
   where not exists
        ( 
           select * from SouthOperation Sop where 
              not exists
              ( 
                select *from PilotGroup  as pg2 where ( pg1.pilot = pg2.pilot) 
                 and 
                (pg2.plane= Sop.plane)
               )
        )
```

Is there any alternatives to search the rows against other table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
    pilot 
from 
    pilotgroup pg 
    inner join
    southoperation sop on (pg.plane = sop.plane)
group by 
    pilot
having 
    count(pg.plane) = (select count(*) from southoperation)
```

Comment: With reference to AakashM's answer, just to clarify, the solution here is to present pilots trained in all planes listed in SouthOperation, without needing to know which planes are in that table.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT Pilot FROM PilotGroup
INNER JOIN SouthOperation ON PilotGroup.Plane = SouthOperation.Plane
GROUP BY Pilot
HAVING COUNT(SouthOperation.Plane) = 2
```

Answer (score 2):

> The task is to print the pilot names who is trained on both A1-Fighter and B1-Fighter.

If you have these values up front, you don't need `SouthOperation` at all:

```
SELECT Pilot FROM PilotGroup WHERE Plane = 'A1-Fighter'
INTERSECT
SELECT Pilot FROM PilotGroup WHERE Plane = 'B1-Fighter'
```

If however you actually mean "print the names of pilots who are trained on all the planes in `SouthOperation`", my question to you is: are there only ever two rows in `SouthOperation` ? Or potentially more?

Answer (score 2):

The question you've posted almost exactly fits the examples in this article by Joe Celko: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), and indeed, covers the fact that the "proper" term for this is relational division.

Comment: +1 The Question reminded me of that example immediately as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @t table (pilot int, plane int);

insert into @t
 select * from (select 1 pilot, 1 plane union all
select 1, 2 union all
select 2, 1 union all
select 3, 3 union all
select 4, 1 union all
select 4, 2) t

select t1.pilot
from @t t1, @t t2 
where t1.pilot = t2.pilot and t1.plane = 1 and t2.plane = 2
group by t1.pilot
```